# CheckBoxPreference does not persist the checked value?

Tags: android

I have this Preference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="sound"
    android:summary="Sound ON/OFF"
    android:title="Sound" >
</CheckBoxPreference>

<PreferenceScreen
    android:key="videos"
    android:persistent="false"
    android:summary="Click to select videos"
    android:title="Videos" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_crimson"
        android:key="crimson"
        android:title="Cimson Cartoon" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_darkgreen"
        android:key="darkgreen"
        android:title="Dark Green Cartoon" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_openfieldrifle"
        android:key="openfieldrifle"
        android:title="Open Field with Bullet Bill, Assault Rifle" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_openfieldshotgun"
        android:key="openfiledshotgun"
        android:title="Open Field Cartoon Shotgun" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_submachine"
        android:key="submachine"
        android:title="Submachine Dark Mist" />
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_violet"
        android:key="violet"
        android:title="Violet Cartoon" />
</PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Now,

In my PreferenceActivity, apparently the checked value are not persisted:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
Boolean crimson;
Boolean darkgreen;
Boolean openfieldrifle;
Boolean openfiledshotgun;
Boolean submachine;
Boolean violet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("prefs");
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefs, false);
    Preference crimsonpreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "crimson");
    Preference darkgreenpreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "darkgreen");
    Preference openfieldriflepreference = getPreferenceScreen()
            .findPreference("openfieldrifle");
    Preference openfiledshotgunpreference = getPreferenceScreen()
            .findPreference("openfiledshotgun");
    Preference submachinepreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "submachine");
    Preference violetpreference = getPreferenceScreen().findPreference(
            "violet");

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyPreferencesActivity.this);
    crimson = sharedPref.getBoolean("crimson", false);
    darkgreen = sharedPref.getBoolean("darkgreen", false);
    openfieldrifle = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfieldrifle", false);
    openfiledshotgun = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfiledshotgun", false);
    submachine = sharedPref.getBoolean("submachine", false);
    violet = sharedPref.getBoolean("violet", false);

    crimsonpreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(listener1);

}

Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener listener1 = new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyPreferencesActivity.this);
        crimson = sharedPref.getBoolean("crimson", false);
        darkgreen = sharedPref.getBoolean("darkgreen", false);
        openfieldrifle = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfieldrifle", false);
        openfiledshotgun = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfiledshotgun", false);
        submachine = sharedPref.getBoolean("submachine", false);
        violet = sharedPref.getBoolean("violet", false);
        Log.e("crimson", Boolean.toString((Boolean) newValue));
        Log.e("darkgreen", Boolean.toString(darkgreen));
        Log.e("openfieldrifle", Boolean.toString(openfieldrifle));
        Log.e("openfiledshotgun", Boolean.toString(openfiledshotgun));
        Log.e("submachine", Boolean.toString(submachine));
        Log.e("violet", Boolean.toString(violet));

        if ((Boolean) newValue || darkgreen || openfieldrifle || openfiledshotgun
                || submachine || violet) {
            return true;
        }
        // If now create a message to the user
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MyPreferencesActivity.this,
                    "Please select at least one video ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    }
};



}
```

For example:

[image]

**But this is what my Log shows!!!**

[image]

Comment: how many identical listeners do you have ? also, post your stacktrace as text, this is not readable.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks  njzk2, if you look carefully they are not identical. Ayway the Log shows `crimson=true`, `darkgreen=false`, `openfieldrifle=false`, `openfieldshotgun=false`, `submachine=false`, `violet =false` . **THE POINT IS THAT I WOULD EXPECT darkgreen=true**

Comment: Indeed, you'd only need 1 only listener.

Comment: @Tobor thanks Tobor, but I do not think the problem is there :-(((

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747164/setonpreferencechangelistener-is-called-when-assigning-listener-to-preference-in

Comment: @keshav thank you keshav, but I do not think this is the cause of the problem

Comment: You want to keep at least one of the checkboxes checked? What's the initial state (e.g., all checkboxes unchecked) before any user interaction?

Comment: @shoerat Thant's correct  shoerat! Initial status in only one preference checked  `<CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_crimson"
        android:key="crimson"
        android:title="Cimson Cartoon" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem comes from this line:

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("prefs");
```

If you remove it, it should work. If you want to keep it, then you should try to replace this line:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyPreferencesActivity.this);
```

By this one:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: removing  `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("prefs");` did the trick. Thanks Addrallyn !!!!

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues with your code.  One is that you are only calling `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` on `crimsonPreference`. You need to do that for all the `Preference` objects. The second is that you cannot call to get the value of the `Preference` from the listener since the value has not been updated yet, according to the doc:

> Sets the callback to be invoked when this Preference is changed by the user (but before the internal state has been updated).

Comment: thak you Scott, indeed I put a listener on all preferences (but did not want post whole thing). The point is that as you can see from inside the "crimson" listener, the value of **darkgreen is FALSE**, but I checked the `darkgreen` checkbox BEFORE checking `crimson`... so your statement:     _"Sets the callback to be invoked when this Preference is changed by the user (but before the internal state has been updated)"_      **does not apply in this case!**  :-((((

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading the preference values from `SharedPreferences`, you are reading the value that was previously set (i.e., before checking or unchecking the `CheckBoxPreference`).

That's, in your listener, you have to make sure to reverse the value of the preference being unchecked (because that's what is going to happen).

So, `onPreferenceChange()` should look something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {

    if ((Boolean)newValue) {
        // Just fall through and enable the option
        return true;
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MyPreferencesActivity.this);
    crimson = sharedPref.getBoolean("crimson", true) // default return value should be true for this
            && !preference.equals(crimsonpreference);
    darkgreen = sharedPref.getBoolean("darkgreen", false)
            && !preference.equals(darkgreenpreference);
    openfieldrifle = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfieldrifle", false)
            && !preference.equals(openfieldriflepreference);
    openfiledshotgun = sharedPref.getBoolean("openfiledshotgun", false)
            && !preference.equals(openfiledshotgunpreference);
    submachine = sharedPref.getBoolean("submachine", false)
            && !preference.equals(submachinepreference);
    violet = sharedPref.getBoolean("violet", false)
            && !preference.equals(violetpreference);

    if (darkgreen || openfieldrifle || openfiledshotgun || submachine || violet) {
        return true;
    }
    // If now create a message to the user
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MyPreferencesActivity.this,
                "Please select at least one video ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.